# Convert SVG to DXF in Inkscape CLI

Tags: svg, inkscape, dxf

I wonder how can we convert **SVG** to **DXF** in Inkscape CLI mode. IN GUI to export/save svg to dxf we can do it from file menu by doing Save As

i went through inkscape cli document : https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html

here mostly export words is used  , so i tried

```
inkscape --export-type=out.dxf in.svg
inkscape --export-filename=out.dxf in.svg
```

but no success giving me errpr

```
InkFileExportCmd::export: Unknown export type: out.dxf. Allowed values: [svg,png,ps,eps,pdf,emf,wmf,xaml].
```

however in GUI under FILE -> SAVE AS we can see a lot of file formats  including DXF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run the extension from the command line, using the available parameters. Find it in your Inkscape installation folder, inside the directory `/share/inkscape/extensions`.

So, in the most basic version:

```
python3 dxf_outlines.py  --output="yourfile.dxf" "yourfile.svg"
```

You can also type

```
python3 dxf_outlines.py -h
```

to find out all about the options.

Comment: thanks :) i had done it like that already , thanks for posting it , forgot about the question

Comment: inkscape already come with python so better to use it , as this may not work with python v2 etc

Comment: Sorry, @user889030 - what do you mean? Is there anything that will improve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using sample code:

```
// command:

C:\>F:\inkscape\bin\inkscape --export-filename=F:\aaa.dxf F:\valve.svg
```

Although there was no tracing back messages, but it succeeded:

[image: aaa.dxf converted by inkscape]

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained why it answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.